# Building workspace' has encountered a problem when i try to import spark to a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark, nullpointerexception

When i try to import spark with "Build path --> configure build path --> Add external jar" into the new project and when i click 'apply and close' button, i see  :

[image: this error].

I have already seen the same problems in stackoverflow but i could not solve the problem.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to add external jars if you're using Maven?

Comment: @cricket_007 i saw the video in youtube what does the same thing. What can i do now?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. I've completely switched to using Intellij

Comment: Have you tried removing the JAR you added? Can you show your POM? Are you able to build the project from command line?

Comment: My pom file is : <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

Comment: But i have an error : Missing artifacts org.apache.org: etc...

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional information. Also, Spark 2.4.4 requires Scala 2.12, meaning you'd want spark-core_2.12

Comment: It's org.apache.spark... You put `org.apache.org`

Comment: I'm a new developper in spark with java. So if you have any link or others which can help me. Please share

Comment: I edit to org.apache.spark but it's the same error

Comment: It can't possibly be the same error. You don't have `org.apache.org` anymore, so it's definitely a different error. And there's plenty of source code examples in Spark official Github

Comment: @cricket_007 So that the pom file can see org.apache.spark. What can i do?

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007. I just change the artifactId in <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>. And it's works

Comment: Okay, so problem solved? Or Eclipse is still unhappy?

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you for your help